# Borland Assertion failed in local_unwind()

Tags: c++, c++builder, assertions

I have a comms server that is supposed to run for an indefinite amount of time. However, it sometimes errors with

> Assertion failed: !"bogus context in Local_unwind()", file xx.cpp, line 2262

which is followed by

> Abnormal Program Termination

after which pressing ok causes the program to disappear. This problem happens intermittently on several computers and is not easily reproducible. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the program code is corrupting the stack before cleanup of a scope/function's stack-based variables can be performed.

Answer (score 0):

Something in your program called longjmp (c) or executed a throw statement (c++). Local_unwind is an internal piece of the borland runtime that is trying to clean up the stack.

If you don't control the source of this program, of course, you've posted this question in the wrong place.